# Why does my magento script use more than 128MB of memory?

Tags: php, magento

As this title says, I've got the following bit of code that I've reduced down for the purpose of this question. It runs out of memory showing:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 548 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\whiterunway-migration\magento\lib\Zend\Db\Statement\Pdo.php on line 228
```

But I can't work out why. I'm overwriting the $product variable on each iteration.

```
$product_ids = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$products_out = [];
foreach ( $product_ids as $product_id ) {
  $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id->getId());
  $a = $product->getMetaTitle();
}
echo count($products_out);
```

I can't quite see any memory leak here.

Comment: Why "allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes"???  Isn't that just a bit small???

Comment: @paulsm4 I don't think so. For what I'm doing, it shouldn't go anywhere near that

Comment: Because the realistic base memory_limit for anything Magento is 256M and then I'd start worrying. How big is this number of products? At 5k, 256M, at 10k, 512M as you are doing an unfiltered getCollection() to get a big batch of objects, not just ids.

Comment: Thanks @FiascoLabs. I guess the fact that I could fit the collection as well as a single loaded product at one time without looping made be think there was plenty of memory. Upping it has helped

Answer (score 2):

The memory is running out because you're loading the objects of all the products into memory. with the line:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id->getId());
```

The line isn't necessary once the collection is loaded

Also:

```
$a = $product->getMetaTitle();
```

should change to

```
$a =$product_id->getMetaTitle();
```